# Error al asignar respuesta a mi modelo node js

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, sequelize.js

tengo el siguiente problema: Tengo la respuesta del webservice en mi controlador, esta respuesta la asigno atraves de un array y quiero asignarla en el modelo que cree para insertar la informacion que llega de este service en la base de datos y recibo el siguiente error:

```
  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Ilicito.create is not a function
    at insertarILicitos (C:\Users\sortegaf\Documents\Interlaft-sqlserver\InterLAFT+\api-laft\controllers\consulta.js:146:58)
    at consultarDocumento (C:\Users\sortegaf\Documents\Interlaft-sqlserver\InterLAFT+\api-laft\controllers\consulta.js:157:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:40244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:40244) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Esta es la logica que se desarrollo para el controlador:

```
    const Empleado = require("../models/empleado");
const Ilicito = require("../models/ilicitos");
const soap = require('../services/index')
const response = require("express");
const convert = require('xml-js')


const actualizarEstado = (req, res) => {
     
}

const consultarDocumento = async(req, res = response) => {

    let {
        objeto,
        objetoFinal
    } = req.body;

    const numDocumento = req.params.numDocumento;

    console.log('mirar esto ->',numDocumento)
    

    try {
        // inicia try
        const existeDocumento = await Empleado.findOne({ where: { numeroDeDocumento : numDocumento } })

        if (!existeDocumento) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: 'El documento no se encuentra registrado',
            });
        }
         else  {

           
            const user = await soap.apiSoap(numDocumento).then((body) => {
                return body;
            }).catch((message) => {
                return message;
            });


            const result = await convert.xml2json(user, { compact: true, spaces: 4 });
            const jsonResult = await JSON.parse(result);

            const message1 = await jsonResult["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["ns1:obtenerLaftXMLUncodedResponse"]["ns1:obtenerLaftXMLUncodedReturn"]._text;
            const result1 = await convert.xml2json(message1, { compact: true, spaces: 4 });
            const jsonResult1 = await JSON.parse(result1);

            
            if ("RESPUESTA_PRODUCTO" in jsonResult1) {
                res.status(503).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: jsonResult1.RESPUESTA_PRODUCTO.ERROR.DETALLE_ERROR._text
                });
            } else {

                
                const incidenteUser = await jsonResult1["RETURN"];

                
                if (incidenteUser["NUMERO_OCURRENCIAS"]._text <= 0) {

                    
                    consolo.log("el pana no tiene ilicitos")
              

             } else  {
                 
                    console.log("el pana si tiene ilictos entonces...")
                    
                    

                    let cantidadIlicitos = incidenteUser["RESPUESTA_LAFT"].ILICITOS_RESPUESTA;
                    let incidentes = [];

                    for (var posicion in cantidadIlicitos) {
                        const datos = {
                            _attributes: cantidadIlicitos[posicion]._attributes.NUM_REG,
                            porcentaje: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].PORCENTAJE._text,
                            campo_buscado: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].CAMPO_BUSCADO._text,
                            valor_buscado: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].VALOR_BUSCADO._text,
                            registro: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].REGISTRO._text,
                            tipo_lista: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].TIPO_LISTA._text,
                            nombre_completo: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].NOMBRECOMPLETO._text,
                            nit: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].NIT._text,
                            fuente: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].FUENTE._text,
                            fecha_update: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].FECHA_UPDATE._text,
                            //estado: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].ESTADO,
                            motivo: cantidadIlicitos[posicion].MOTIVO_INGRESO._text
                        };
                        incidentes.push(datos);
                        
                    }

                    const insertarILicitos = async(req, res) => {

                        const ilicitosOK = await Ilicito.create({incidentes})
                                  
                        res.status(200).json({
                            success: true,
                            message: "termino la logica",
                            ilicitosOK
                         
                         })
                         
                    }

                    insertarILicitos(incidentes)
                    
               

                }

            }
        }

      
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'Error inesperado',
        });
    }

   
}

    module.exports = {
        consultarDocumento,
        actualizarEstado
    };
```

Actualmente estoy utilizando nodejs y el ORM sequalize dado que tengo que insertar el array en Sqlserver, la informacion la mando en un string dado que no puedo insertar arrays en sqlserver.

Muchas gracias por la atención